# Site cannot access external connection

Tags: php, wp-config

my WordPress site cannot access external connection (e.g. cannot browse/update plugins using dashboard - manual zip install only). The site is can be access from the outside world (via domain name) but from the inside it can't.

I have try to set the `WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL` in `wp-config.php` to `false` but the result still the same.

```php
define('WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', false);
```

The web server is running on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS using Ajenti V (I did not set the server up myself so I don't know is there any configuration that blocks the outside connection or not)

I want to know is there anywhere I should look for inside the WordPress or even the outside (the webserver configuration itself)

Comment: This is my first question on this community. I don't know what tag I should use about this question. If there're the more appropriate tags, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: It's going to be server configuration I'd think, either some sort of outbound firewall or a per-user outbound connection restriction or something like SELinux - but I wouldn't know where to look in Ubuntu sorry. Or it could be a firewall on the network that the server is hosted in blocking connections. I'd talk to whoever set the server up.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking into the firewall as well but still no solution. And about your last suggestion. I don't know whoever set this server up 5 years ago. They just gave me full access to this server and tell me to fix it. That's might be a problem.

Comment: Although the problem you're having is in Wordpress, this question isn't specific to Wordpress, it's most likely how your web server (e.g. apache), server or network are setup. You may want to ask this question in Stack Overflow or Server Fault where they can help you diagnose it from the command line.